# Can you help me with this multiplier problem of lagrange multipliers?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, systems-of-equations, lagrange-multiplier, hessian-matrix

$f\left(x,y\right) = x^4 + 3y^{\frac{4}{3}}$ with restriction $xy = c$ and the constant $c > 0$. I can't find a way to find the critical points with Lagrange multipliers.

I put together the following system of equations:

$$
L_x = 4x^3 - y \cdot \lambda = 0 \\
L_y = 4\sqrt[3]{y} - x \cdot \lambda = 0 \\
L_\lambda = x \cdot y - c=0
$$

Comment: First solve the third equation for $y$ in terms of $x$ and $c$, then substitute that into the first two equations.  Then solve the first equation for $\lambda$ in terms of $x$ and $c$, and substitute that into the second equation.  Then solve that for $x$.

Comment: Actually, I would recommend a slightly different order.  You'll notice that the $x$ and $y$ terms of the second equation are consistently the cube roots of the corresponding terms in the first.  So rearrange, cube, and cancel to get an equation you can solve for $\lambda$.  Then solve the first equation for $y$ in terms of $x$ and substitute into the third equation.

Comment: In any case: **what are you stuck with?**  You've reduced a Lagrange multipliers problem to solving a system of simultaneous equations; what aspect of that system of equations is troubling you?

Comment: @JacobManaker I find that possible solution interesting, but I don't understand what you mean by rearranging

Comment: @JacobManakerIt is that I cannot find the correct way to find the critical points through the system of equations

Comment: Take first equation: $ 4x^3 - y \cdot \lambda = 0 \implies \lambda = \dfrac{4x^3}{y}$ for $y \ne 0$. Now substitute this in the second equation and you get $x^4 = y^{4/3}$ i.e $y =  x^3$. Now $xy = c$ constraint gives you $(x,y)$. Pls check other possible values.

Answer (score 1):

There is a critical point at $(0,0).$  As for the others.

From the 3rd equation: $x = \frac {c}{y}$

Substituting into the first equation:
$4x^3 - y\lambda = 0\\
\frac {4c^3}{y^3} = y\lambda\\
\lambda = 4c^3y^4$

And the 2nd:

$4y^{\frac 13} = \lambda x\\
4y^{\frac 13} = 4c^3y^4\frac {c}{y}\\
y^{-\frac {8}{3}} = c^4\\
y = 2^{-\frac {3}{4}} c^{-\frac 32}$

knowing $y$ we can find $x$ and $f(x,y).$

$x = \frac {c}{y} = 2^{\frac 34}c^{\frac 52}\\
f(x,y) = x^4 + 3y^{\frac 43} =8c^{10}+\frac {3}{2c^2}$

And there should also be a maximum at $(x,y) = (-2^{\frac 34}c^{\frac 52},-2^{-\frac 34} c^{-\frac 32})$

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the multiplier $\lambda$, in this kind of cases ($n=2$ with only one constraint) it is recommended to work with a determinant as follows to reduce the dimension of the system obtained by the LM.

Let $g(x, y)=xy-c$ be the constraint function ($xy=c$ is equivalent to $g(x, y)=0$). Since for your critical point $\nabla f(x, y)=\lambda\nabla g(x, y)$, then the vectors $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ are linearly dependent, so
\begin{align*}
\text{det}(\nabla f\ \ \nabla g)=0\ \Longrightarrow 4x^4-4y^{4/3}=0.
\end{align*}
It follows that $x=y^{1/3}$ and then from the constraint $xy=c>0$ you can obtain the critical point(s). Here there is only one and by inspection it is a maximum.